# Spring bean instantiation by passing constructor args?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have below spring bean.

```
public class Employee2 {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private double salary;


  public Employee2(int id, String name, double salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
  }

 // some logic to call database using above values

}
```

Now i have below config in spring configuration file.

```
<bean id="emp2" class="com.basic.Employee2">
            <constructor-arg name="id" value="" />
            <constructor-arg name="name" value="" />
            <constructor-arg name="salary" value="" />
</bean>
```

Now i cannot hard code the values in above config since they are dynamic.

Now i am getting spring bean programmatically using below code. **The bean scope is singelton**.

```
Employee2 emp = (Employee2)applicationContext.getBean("emp2");
```

Now **how can i pass the values to Employee2 constructor**?

Thanks!

Comment: If they are dynamic but you know them at start time you should use `spel` (spring expression language) or property-placeholders to configure them on start up. You say that's a singleton so most probably that's your case.

If that's not the case, you probably should not create it as singleton bean.

Anyway - I would avoid completely the `getBean` methodology. You have such a great infrastructure for decoupling the injections. Why would you want to couple it again?

Comment: Avi, Thanks for your reply. First, do The Employee2 bean be Singleton scope or prototype bean? Because my bean just contains setters and getters for the fields and a method to call some DAO logic. In this case do i need to go for prototype scope?

Comment: bellabax, thanks for providing the link. In my case do i need my bean in prototype scope?

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496693/passing-spring-constructor-arg-to-another-ref-bean/18497016#18497016

Comment: Yes. Are you sure you need only ONE instance of bean? As @Avi wrote I think you are looking for a prototype scope to obtain a new fresh instance of your bean every time

Comment: My Bean is just a POJO to set some search criteria. It is more of DTO. Do i need to go for prototype scope?

Comment: Probably you need a DAO with a `search(id,name,salary)` function and not a powered POJO...

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [ApplicationContext#getBean(String name, Object ... params)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getBean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method, which

> Allows for specifying explicit constructor arguments / factory method
>   arguments, overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the
>   bean definition.

For example:

```
Integer param1 = 2;
String param2 = "test";
Double param3 = 3.4;
Employee2 emp = 
          (Employee2)applicationContext.getBean("emp2", param1, param2, param3);
```

Anyway, while this will possibly work, you should consider using *Spring EL*, as noted in one of the comments under the question.

Comment: kocko, does it work with singleton bean?because link says... arguments to use if creating a prototype using explicit arguments to a static factory method. It is invalid to use a non-null args value in any other case.

Comment: the type of the bean doesn't matter, I think. You can try it out and share the results. :)

Comment: Actually, I would be surprised if it works for singletons...

Comment: i tried..got exception..saying getBean args should be used only with prototype scope...

Comment: This shouldn't be surprising. Otherwise it would break the rules for immutability.

Comment: If i use prototype then does spring manages my bean instances?

Comment: can i annotate prototype beans with @Transactional ?

Comment: It actually will work with Singletons, as long as they are not created eagerly ( for example if marked with @Lazy ). However this is undocumented behavior, and also a bit nonsensical as only the parameters supplied on the first call to getBean will be used.