# Spring pass parameter to constructor context.getBean

Tags: java, spring

I was trying to pass the constructor parameter dynamically to a bean in the Springboot framework. I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829162/spring-bean-instantiation-by-passing-constructor-args) using context.getBean(class, arg...) to pass the constructor parameters dynamically in Spring, but it did not successfully get the value and display the default values. What is wrong with my code?

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="opBean" class="com.testout.service.Operation">
        <constructor-arg name="param1" value="default1" />
        <constructor-arg name="param2" value="default2" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Application**

```
import com.testout.service.Operation;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        String param1 = "newValue1";
        String param2 = "newValue2";
        Operation op = (Operation) context.getBean("opBean", param1, param2);
        op.printParams();
    }
}
```

**Operation**

```
package com.testout.service;

public class Operation {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public Operation(String param1, String param2){

        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
        System.out.println("param1: " + param1 + ", param2: " + param2);
    }
    public void printParams(){

        System.out.println(this.param1);
        System.out.println(this.param2);
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
2021-02-19 16:45:58.201  INFO 43664 --- [           main] com.testout.controller.Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-19 16:45:59.097  INFO 43664 --- [           main] com.testout.controller.Application       : Started Application in 1.494 seconds (JVM running for 2.074)
param1: default1, param2: default2
default1
default2
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want this behavior you have to set the `scope` of your bean to `prototype`

```
<bean id="opBean" class="com.testout.service.Operation" scope="prototype"/>
```

Comment: set this property in your xml <bean id="opBean" class="com.testout.service.Operation" scope="prototype"/>